# Preg match integers separated by white spaces

Tags: regex

Sorry for such a basic question but I can't find this elsewhere

How could I find/echo the integers in a string (separated by white space) like this:

```
Find the integers 24 / 850
```

how could I return just 24, or 850?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fetch the groups with the regex in the example: [Preview](http://www.rubular.com/r/AlJqhWrVTG)

So to get the groups, you could use (\d+)

Comment: Thanks for the example as well!

Answer (score 1):

how about using `(\d)+`?

`\d` means digits.